# How to organise an i-graph directed network along a time axis?

Tags: networking, time, tree, igraph, citations

I am creating a network of scientific literature, where nodes represent publications and edges citations. I used igraph to plot my example set in a circle layout.

[Network,organized in circle layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pe3xt.png)

What I wnat to do next is organize the network on a time axis. I have the publication year as node-attribute in a column of the nodes file. Is there a way to organize this directed network by time? 
The result should finally a bit like this:
[Citationnetwork, y-axis=timeline, created with www.citnetexplorer.nl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swarh.png)

One idea could be a treelayout and then truncating each year - tried hard, but couldn't manage. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution (or timely given that this question is over three years old...), but it might work if the network is small.

You can use `tkplot()`, which will pull up a window to help you manually plot the nodes. You need to have XQuartz if you're running things on a mac. The clearest bit of instruction I've found is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZAkYM29tsY).